# Insert line breaks in title sections (of SVG) using xml.etree.ElementTree without getting actualnewlines in the file

Tags: python, xml, svg

I'm generating an SVG file (which is an XML file) using python and the xml.etree.ElementTree module. A lot of elements in the file are like this

```xml
<path class="grp8" d="m 384.65741,247.48752 -7.87275,1.86375 -7.42575,2.0895 3.177,9.747 7.36425,-2.05725 6.885,-1.61925 -2.12775,-10.02375 z"><title>Thomas Cazenave
1e circo. Gironde</title></path>
```

Notice the line break between the family name and the number.
For readability reasons, I'd like for each `path` to be on a single line, so to get that line break out of the *file*. However, I want the end result to be the same, with a line break in the tooltip when the user hovers the path.

I tried writing `"&#10;"` instead of `"\n"` in the Python strings being assembled to form the XML elements, but they get protected by the ElementTree.write function, and the file ends with `&amp;#10;` being written instead. (I also tried inserting `<br/>` and it got protected too but later learned it's not supposed to work anyway.)

How can I make it so that the end SVG gets its line breaks, without being represented as \n characters in the raw file ?

An example of how I'm building the XML structure (the full code is [here](https://github.com/Gouvernathor/parliamentdiagram/blob/french-hemi/frencharch.py)) :

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

svg = ET.Element('svg', xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
elem = ET.Element("path", {"class":"grp8"} d="m 853.54468...")
title = ET.Element("title")
# title.text = "Thomas Cazenave\n1e circo..." # ends up with actual linebreaks in the resulting file
title.text = "Thomas Cazenave&#xA;1e circo..." # the "&" is escaped at the .write phase and the "&#xA;" is visible verbatim in the resulting tooltip.
elem.append(title)
svg.append(elem)

tree = ET.ElementTree(svg)
with open("./frencharch.svg", "wb") as f:
    tree.write(f, encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True)
```

Comment: `&#xA;` should work but please add your python code. Questions are encouraged to provide a [mcve]

Comment: @LMC doesn't work, same result, the & gets escaped. Example added.